# In the director's cut of Alien, Ripley in her final report lists also Ash as being dead — why?

Tags: alien-franchise

Bottom Line: I am accepting the answer and I think the report is a very deliberate attempt by Ripley to signal she will cooperate and/or is ignorant. She of course was furious at what had been done but when you are light years' away from home and completely alone except for a cat, you probably decide that getting back there is all that you want and a gesture, especially an utterly futile one since only the company would see the message, was not what she wanted to make. Perhaps some sequels later she wondered if she should have just made the gesture and spent a peaceful eternity in deep space.

She lists the entire crew in her last report as 3rd Officer before going into hibernation (that she has no idea how long will last) including Ash as being dead. I wonder why she would fail to note, in fact seems to maintain the dangerous fiction that he was a human, that he was an android. The only reason I can think she would pretend that she did not know that the company had placed an android secretly among the crew is that it is likely that if she was rescued it would be by a company ship and maybe if they thought she would make legal trouble, they might not revive her at all.

The key idea is that a proper report would have assigned blame to Ash for the deaths of the crew rather than just implying that he also was killed by the same organism. Again, unless her goal was simply to be rescued and to not have any rescuers waste time looking for any other crew members.

EDIT: I think the point as has been suggested is that Ripley is being very careful. She wants to be rescued as unlikely as that is; she also knows that the company of course knows what they did, in particular putting an android in the crew. The only thing the company does not know for certain is that Ripley also knows this -- it is possible that the creature destroyed Ash or that she never discovered that he was an android and he was blown up with the Nostromo.

So: She is being very deliberate, either signaling ignorance or that she will play along if rescued. She expects that a rescue attempt is possible since she probably knows some valuable stuff (in fact she does). If she was found by accident in Aliens, she was still taken care of precisely because she knew things they wanted. I don't recall whether she continued to pretend once revived -- I am pretty sure she did not play it cool once other people on Earth knew of her.

But for sure if she had said, You bastards, you are responsible for the deaths of almost an entire crew, she could have sealed her fate. Maybe they still would have rescued her, debriefed her and then just killed her -- it is indeed, obviously, a ruthless and powerful company.

EDIT: One thought is that the company had decided in fact not to rescue her although I still think they would have wanted the information she potentially had. An emergency craft would have some robust beaconing system. When she was eventually rescued was it by "blind luck" or did the company at the highest levels finally decide they needed her? (Of course this may not really be logically consistent -- it is just a sequel, after all.)

Comment: Just because his organs are artificial doesn't mean he isn't alive.

Comment: but that he was an android is the key idea. i am not saying he was not alive but he is just listed as another member of the crew which is the crux of the question. one might have thought she would say, an alien organism was brought onboard which killed our entire crew and the company was complicit in this, planting an android which helped cause the disaster but she did not not.

Comment: “a proper report would have assigned blame to Ash for the deaths of the crew” — would it? Why? Because he let the crew back in after Kane got face-hugged? The rest of the crew were pretty keen to break quarantine protocol too; I think Ripley was the only one who thought they should stick to it. After that, Ash attempts to kill Ripley, but fails. The crew die because of the alien, not Ash.

Comment: Admitting that she knew Ash was an android and that there was a plot by Wayland Yutani to have the crew infected by the xenomorph could be dangerous once she got back to civilization.

Comment: Per Stack Exchange rules, cross-posting is forbidden; please pick a site and stick to it. https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/111928/63559

Comment: Klaus above hits on my thoughts about this - you know that you were diverted by the company to investigate an alien signal, you know that the company swapped out a crew member for an android without telling you, you know that the company ensured the android had none of the usual preventative limits protecting action against humans, so its a logical conclusion that the company would be looking for you should you fail to report in, so theres no reason to advertise that you know these things otherwise you aren't going to be woken up to implicate them when they do indeed find you...

Comment: @Moo: i would accept that as answer. she is trying to make it clear either that she knows nothing or will "play ball" to encourage them to rescue her which even though expensive would provide valuable information.

Comment: Your edits to this question have made it very long and confusing to read. Please remember that this is not a discussion forum. The question box should contain a question, and the answer box should contain an answer, and if you're looking to have more of a back-and-forth than that, this isn't the right site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets think about this for a second.

1. You know that the company knew about the alien signal, and that the company knew it was a warning and not a rescue beacon
2. You know that the company diverted your ship to investigate, without telling you or involving you before you started the trip
3. You know that the company swapped out one of your crew members for an android, again without telling you
4. You know that the android knew about the real mission
5. You know that the android had none of the usual behavioural limits on causing harm to humans
6. You know the [androids special order](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA8jv1M6Y2g) is "bring back life form, priority one, all other priorities rescinded"
7. You know that Mother, the ships computer, has [Special Order 937](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6mvwOCYJjc): "Priority One. Insure (sic) return of organism for analysis.  All other considerations secondary.  ***Crew expendable***.". Emphasis mine.

[image: Special Order 937]

Its pretty easy to come to the conclusion that the company is a threat to you, and that they are probably going to be the ones picking you up, so the best thing you can do to ensure they actually wake you up is to lie in the reports they will read before waking you up, pretend you don't know anything about the real reasons and that the mission just went bad unexpectedly.

Comment: watching Aliens -- once rescued, she no longer is quiet about anything it does not seem like. the rescue also appears (and since it happens 57 years later) completely accidental. however, although she show antipathy towards bishop, i don't think she has outright accused the company of sacrificing the crew and using ash to help get the xeno onboard.

Comment: @releseabe But in Aliens, _shes been woken up_, so she can defend herself and thats the logical intention in lying in the report - plus she did not know that she wasn't going to get picked up, she might have assumed (pure speculation) that given the investment the company had made, they might have a second ship waiting to step in and pick up survivors immediately. In fact, from the way the company reacts in Aliens, it turns out that this was all probably a side mission by a middle manager somewhere who covered it up once the ship didn't make port, otherwise where was the followup missions?

Comment: @releseabe in Aliens, Burke didn't even know about the true intention of the Nostromos mission - he had to send some of the colonists on LV-426 out to the spot Ripley gave the hearing, and then he got a Colonial Marines detachment sent out when the colony went dark - but there were no special orders for the Marines (that we know of, Gorman etc didn't seem to know about the aliens thats for sure), no special abilities for Bishop etc, just Burke on his own.  So where was the company followup?  It didn't seem to exist by Aliens.

Comment: "insure" is not a misspelling in American English. It means what "ensure" means in British/Australian/Irish/Indian etc. English